# Converter PDF para Imagem em PHP

Tags: php, pdf

Existe alguma maneira de converter arquivos PDF para imagens `(JPG, PNG, ...)`?

Comment: Vai te ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227014/convert-pdf-to-jpeg-with-php-and-imagemagick

Comment: Primeiro, agradeço ao Guilherme pela correção de português e também ao Rafael pela ajuda.

Comment: @RafaelWithoeft, considere colocar a resposta do `SO` aqui, para ajudar a nossa comunidade.